# Как сделать таблицы одинаковыми по размерам в html?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код 4 таблиц - 3 таблицу идут в линию, а 4 находится под первой таблицей. Я установил widht на ячейки и теперь таблицы полностью одинаковые. Но если изменится размер экрана - таблицы не будут одинаковыми. Мне нужно чтобы и при изменении расширения экрана таблицы оставались одинаковыми по длине.

Код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.tables-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Бетон
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Бетона
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за 1м2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          3200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          3300р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          3500р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          3800р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          4000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          4200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-400/ В 30 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          4600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-450/ В 35 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          5000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-500/ В 40 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          5200р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Другие стройматериалы
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за тонну
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Песок
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          1200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Отсев
        </td>
        <td>
          700р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Щебень
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Щебня
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за тонну
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Текст
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          Цена
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          РОМ-50 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          2600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-75 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          2700р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-100 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          2900р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-150 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          3300р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-200 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          3600р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          РПМ-50 на песке
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          3400р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-75 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          3500р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-100 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          3600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-150 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          4000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-200 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          4200р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

P.s Даже при запуске кода на этом сайте видно, что таблицы не одинаковые

Comment: `display: grid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, по-моему, нужно просто обернуть таблицы в первом столбце в один контейнер, а остальное не менять.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.tables-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <div>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Бетон
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Бетона
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за 1м2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          3200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          3300р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          3500р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          3800р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          4000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8
        </td>
        <td>
          4200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-400/ В 30 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          4600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-450/ В 35 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          5000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Бетон М-500/ В 40 пластификатором
        </td>
        <td>
          5200р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <br>
   <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          РОМ-50 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          2600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-75 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          2700р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-100 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          2900р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-150 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          3300р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РОМ-200 на отсеве
        </td>
        <td>
          3600р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <br>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          РПМ-50 на песке
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          3400р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-75 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          3500р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-100 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          3600р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-150 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          4000р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          РПМ-200 на песке
        </td>
        <td>
          4200р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
    
    
    
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Другие стройматериалы
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за тонну
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Песок
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          1200р
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Отсев
        </td>
        <td>
          700р
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px;">
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Щебень
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Тип Щебня
          </td>
          <td>
            Цена за тонну
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px;">
          Текст
        </td>
        <td style="width: 93px;">
          Цена
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас 5 таблиц и 3 обретки.
Для всех обёрток добавьте класс `.tables-wrapper`, а для его дочерних элементов `table` задайте [свойства flex-элемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```
.tables-wrapper table {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
}
```

готовый вариант.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.tables-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.tables-wrapper table {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px"> <!-- ТАБЛИЦА 1 -->
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Бетон
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Тип Бетона</td>
          <td>Цена за 1м2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px">Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором</td>
        <td style="width: 93px">3200р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором</td>
        <td>3300р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором</td>
        <td>3500р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8</td>
        <td>3800р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8</td>
        <td>4000р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8</td>
        <td>4200р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон М-400/ В 30 пластификатором</td>
        <td>4600р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон М-450/ В 35 пластификатором</td>
        <td>5000р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бетон М-500/ В 40 пластификатором</td>
        <td>5200р</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table> 
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px"> <!-- ТАБЛИЦА 2 -->
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Другие стройматериалы
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Тип</td>
          <td>Цена за тонну</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px">Песок</td>
        <td style="width: 93px">1200р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Отсев</td>
        <td>700р</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px"> <!-- ТАБЛИЦА 3 -->
    <caption style="font-size: 130%">
      Щебень
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Тип Щебня</td>
          <td>Цена за тонну</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px">Текст</td>
        <td style="width: 93px">Цена</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <!-- ДОБАВИЛ класс -->
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px"> <!-- ТАБЛИЦА 4 -->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px">РОМ-50 на отсеве</td>
        <td style="width: 93px">2600р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РОМ-75 на отсеве</td>
        <td>2700р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РОМ-100 на отсеве</td>
        <td>2900р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РОМ-150 на отсеве</td>
        <td>3300р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РОМ-200 на отсеве</td>
        <td>3600р</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <!-- ДОБАВИЛ класс -->
  <table style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px"> <!-- ТАБЛИЦА 5 -->
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 296.683px">РПМ-50 на песке</td>
        <td style="width: 93px">3400р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РПМ-75 на песке</td>
        <td>3500р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РПМ-100 на песке</td>
        <td>3600р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РПМ-150 на песке</td>
        <td>4000р</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>РПМ-200 на песке</td>
        <td>4200р</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```